# delete_batch method in Dropbox API using AppsScript

Tags: google-apps-script, dropbox-api, delete-file

I am using AppsScript to manipulate files between GDrive and Dropbox and my current task is to delete a bunch of files from a specified folder in Dropbox.

The App I created has Permission type for App folder only.

Initially I managed to delete a single file, using this method https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-delete
by the following code

```
    function deleteFiles() {
      var dropBoxAccessToken = "token"

      var dropBoxDeleteRes = (deleteDropBoxFiles(dropBoxAccessToken).getContentText())
      Logger.log(dropBoxDeleteRes)  
    }

    function deleteDropBoxFiles(apiKey) {
      return UrlFetchApp.fetch(
      "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/delete_v2",
        {
          "method" : "post",
          "contentType" : "application/json",
          "payload" : JSON.stringify({"path": "/20200110-dsc06071.jpg"}), 
          "headers" : {"Authorization" : "Bearer " + apiKey},
          "muteHttpExceptions" : true     
          }
      );
    }
```

However, I have difficulties in achieving the same for several files.
These files are located in the root folder of the App folder and I have noticed from API docs that this method does not support root folder operations (error: `Error in call to API function "files/delete_batch": request body: entries.path: The root folder is unsupported.`) 
Referring to this method https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-delete_batch I tried to modify the `path` string to something like `{"path":"/\"\""}`,`{"path":"/."}` or `{"path":"/"}` to indicate "all files". Testing it through API Explorer gets me a async_job_ID but files remain not deleted in the folder. However, running the same from within AppsScript returns the following error:

`{"error_summary": "path_lookup/not_found/..", "error": {".tag": "path_lookup", "path_lookup": {".tag": "not_found"}}}` which is evidently a path error.

Feels as though this method cannot delete from the App root folder.

Would appreciate a little help on this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Dropbox API app with the "app folder" cannot issue a deletion for its entire root like this, but I'll pass this along as a feature request. I can't promise if or when that might be implemented though.

Instead, if you want to delete all of the contents of the root folder, you'll need to list each item and issue a delete for each one specifically, either by calling /2/files/delete_v2 once per item, or /2/files/delete_batch with batches listing all of the items.